# Can I use perf_event_open to work in counting mode and sampling mode at the same time?

Tags: counting, sampling, perf

Can I use perf_event_open to work in counting mode and sampling mode at the same time ?  If I can, how to do it?

Comment: You mean so you can get samples but also get an overall total, including any remainder events that weren't enough to trigger a sample when the program ends?

Comment: Please describe more clearly the kind of data you wish to record. What information should be collected at the end of the run? Do you really want to use the `perf_event_open` API or the `perf` tools? It would be best if you can provide a minimal code of what you have and a clear description of what is missing.

Comment: I use perf_event_open() API. I want to count INSTRUCTIONS and sample branch_stack (LBR)  at the same time. I don't know how to do that.......